# What is a good way to bond stuff to silicon nitride?

Tags: epoxy

I am currently looking into attaching a wire onto Silicon Nitride igniter, which is being used as a resistive heater. The problem I am experiencing is that the Silicon nitride is extremely hard to bond things on as is, and in addition, the bonding agent has to be able to tolerate temperatures up to 1K Celsius. I have already experimented with ceramic epoxy and found difficulty.
Alternatively, we have already considered using a silicon Carbide igniter, however, all commercial igniters have bases that are too big for our uses.
It is possible for us to use filaments and create a base, however, we would like to avoid the hassle if possible.
What would be a good way to do this?